# How can one find the sum of node values stored in an XML file through java?

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, sum, nodes

I apologize for the poor formatting and potentially stupid question...I am a noobie in these areas.

I have a simple XML document that I have created to represent a hobby I enjoy, the items required for the hobby, and the price for those items. I am writing a Java application to read the XML file and output it's contents through using nodes. I have gotten that portion of the program to work correctly.

However, what I am trying to figure out is, is it possible to take the values that represent the "price" values I am already pulling, and find the sum of them?

I have read multiple different threads over the internet but none of them seem to fit my scenario.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Wakeboarding>
    <gear>
        <description> Board </description>
        <price currency = "USD"> 400.00 </price>
    </gear>
    <gear>
        <description> Bindings </description>
        <price currency = "USD"> 200.00 </price>
    </gear>
    <gear>
        <description> Helmet </description>
        <price currency = "USD"> 75.00 </price>
    </gear>
    <gear>
        <description> Lifevest </description>
        <price currency = "USD"> 75.00 </price>
    </gear>
    <gear>
        <description> Handle </description>
        <price currency = "USD"> 50.00 </price>
    </gear>
</Wakeboarding>
```

JAVA:

```
public class HobbyReader 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException 
    {
       try 
       {  
    File fXmlFile = new       File("/Users/Pete/Documents/NetBeansProjects/HobbyXML/src/hobby.xml");

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    System.out.println("My Hobby: " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("gear");

    System.out.println("----------------------------");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) 
        {
        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
                { 
            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

            System.out.println("Gear Description: " +                 eElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent());

            System.out.println("Price: " +                       eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent());
                }
        }
```

Output:

```
run:
My Hobby: Wakeboarding
----------------------------
Gear Description:  Board 
Price:  400.00 
Gear Description:  Bindings 
Price:  200.00 
Gear Description:  Helmet 
Price:  75.00 
Gear Description:  Lifevest 
Price:  75.00 
Gear Description:  Handle 
Price:  50.00
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Don't apologize for the formatting, just fix it. As you get each price, add it to a list. When you're done going through the nodes, add all the element prices in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You are already printing the price, so you already have the string value of that number, so you just have to convert that value into a number and sum all of them.

```
double sum = 0.0;
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) 
    {
    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
            { 
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

        System.out.println("Gear Description: " +                 eElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent());

        System.out.println("Price: " +                       eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent());
        sum += Double.parseDouble(eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent());
            }
    }
System.out.println("Total: " + sum);
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, seems like a good way to get it done. The code you provided isn't displaying the sum though, it only outputs the price of the last value, in this case "50".

Comment: You're right. Just forgot to add the printing part. Which should go outside the for loop.

Comment: Alright, I used your input along with Arun's and I believe I have got it working correctly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Pete if the question is solved, select an answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

The change is instead of printing everything, you are having a double variable named value in which you add all the prices. [you need to change it to the type double since raw data that is read is string in java]

```
double value=0.0;
     for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) 
     {
        org.w3c.dom.Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
        { 
           Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

           String price = eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent(); // example String
           value = value + Double.parseDouble(price);
        }
     }
     System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: This worked really well for me; I had to tinker with it a little to get the output the way I wanted, but everything now runs perfect. Thank you very much for your help!